# Applying a hover style to a li:last-child link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have styled an item at the end of the list, which looks great, but I can't seem to make any changes to the hover state:

```css
div#navigation li a{color:#73737a;} 
div#navigation li a:hover{color:#3ca2e0;} 
div#navigation li:last-child{
  border-radius:6px;   
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; padding:6px 9px; color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;     
}

div#navigation li:last-child:hover{
background-color:orange;
}
```

I noticed the li:last-child:hover has no 'Anchor' reference, could this be the problem?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9NXRS/ - can you also post your HTML?

Comment: Sorry I have figured it out. The problem was with my CSS Gradient Backgrounds. Played with the jsfiddle so thanks muchly!

Comment: Question is nonsensical and OP answered in comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
div#navigation li a{color:#73737a;}
div#navigation li a:hover{color:#3ca2e0;} 
div#navigation li#last-child{
  border-radius:6px;   
-webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; padding:6px 9px; color: #fff;
background-color: blue;}

div#navigation li#last-child:hover{
background-color:orange;}
```

Define your (li:last-child) to an ID and then apply the hover properties... hope it'll help...

Answer (score 0):

Solution for SASS/SCSS:

```
li {
  &:last-child {
    // default color
    color: #FFBFBF;
  }

  &:last-child:hover {
    // color on hover
    color: #F00;
  }
}
```